# Handle destination per route in nodejs with multer package

Tags: node.js, multer

I use multer package and make it dynamic and its work. Now it try to make it dynamic per route and stuck with this.

This is my fileupload service:

```
const path = require("path");
const multer = require("multer");
const crypto = require("crypto");
const fs = require("fs-extra");

const today = new Date();
const date = today.getFullYear() + "-" + (today.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + today.getDate();

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, callback) => {
    const { companyID, flowID } = req.body;
    let path = `./uploads/${companyID}/${flowID}`;
    fs.mkdirsSync(path);
    callback(null, path);
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    crypto.pseudoRandomBytes(8, (err, raw) => {
      if (err) return cb(err);
      cb(
        null,
        date + "_" + raw.toString("hex") + "_" + path.extname(file.originalname)
      );
    });
  }
});

//Must be under storage
const upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single("upload");

const deleteFileFromServer = (companyID, flowID, filePath) => {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    fs.unlink(`./uploads/${companyID}/${flowID}/${filePath}`).then(()=>{
      resolve("File Deleted");
    }).catch((err)=> {
      reject(err);
    })
  })
};

module.exports = {
  upload: upload,
  deleteFileFromServer: deleteFileFromServer
};
```

my route: Here i want handle destination in every route set diffrent destination

```
router.post("/uploadfile", upload, (req, res, next) => {
  const file = req.file;
  const flowID = req.body.flowID;
  if (!file) {
    const error = new Error("Please upload a file");
    error.httpStatusCode = 400;
    return next(error);
  } else {
    createFileInDB(file.originalname, flowID, file.filename)
      .then(() => {
        console.log("File Created");
        res.json(file);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send(err);
      });
  }
});
```

What i want it to be? i want that every route i can choose different destination.

```
router.post("/uploadfile", upload, (req, res, next) => {
  upload.destination = "my path/"
});
```

Thanks!!