# Change cloudinary folder per route using multer in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer, cloudinary

Found this guy with a similar question: [Handle destination per route in nodejs with multer package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58954688/handle-destination-per-route-in-nodejs-with-multer-package)

No answer for him, 4 months later, so I'm hoping I have better luck!

I'm using multer-storage-cloudinary to upload files directly to cloudinary without using a temporary local storage, and I need to potentially change the folder where the file is going on a per-route basis.

The documentation for multer-storage-cloudinary leaves a little to be desired, regarding setting a function to set the folder. It gives an example, but doesn't talk at all about what the callback does, what/how gets returned, what the expected arguments are, etc: https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-storage-cloudinary

It *seems* that the second argument in the callback called at the end of the function is what will be returned/set as the folder in Cloudinary--is that correct?

So for example if I were to do this with the form:

```html
<form action="/location" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image">
    <input type="text" value="abcd" name="companyId" hidden>
    <input type="text" value="1234" name="locationId" hidden>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And this in the multer-storage-cloudinary setup (assuming everything else is already set up to use cloudinary):

```js
const storage = cloudinaryStorage({
  cloudinary: cloudinary,
  folder: function(req, file, callback) {
    let path;
    if(req.body.companyId && req.body.locationId) {
        path = `/my-project/${req.body.companyId}/${req.body.locationId}`;
    } else {
        path = '/my-project/uncategorized';
    }
    callback(undefined, path);
  }
});
```

Would that set the folder that the file gets uploaded to as `'/my-project/abcd/1234'`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with multer but with cloudinary, you can set the public_id to  `/my-project/abcd/1234` and it will generate those folders for you (if they do not exist).

Comment: @ShirlyManor how/where would you set that? After the image is uploaded? Somewhere in the cloudinary setup?

Comment: try to set the public_id instead of path. For example public_id = "my-project/uncategorized/name"

Comment: Would a unique ID be added after that to identify it in the future? My understanding is that it's the Public ID that is used to remove images.